# Selective word highlight in SublimeText

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3

Is there any way that i can select some words to be highlighted and their instances as well. This feature i especially used when viewing log files in Notepad++

Comment: When you select a word, its occurrences are already highlighted. Or do you mean "select" them?

Comment: I just want to highlight them then move on with the cursor. Used to assist in viewing logs. Selection is sepearate

Comment: How do you mean "move on with the cursor"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some useful key combos for selecting words in Sublime Text.

---

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> - selects all occurrences of the current word (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd> on Windows/Linux)

<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> - selects the next instance of the current word if it is already selected, otherwise selects the current word (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>)

- <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> - skips the current instance and goes on to select the next one (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>)
- <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> - "soft undo", moves back to the previous selection (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>)

<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> - uses the current selection as the "Find" field in Find and Replace (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>)

---

If you start with an empty selection, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> will search by whole words automatically. If you start with a non-empty selection, it will search for any instance of the text (disregarding word boundaries).

Comment: I just want to highlight them then move on with the cursor. Used to assist in viewing logs. Selection is separate

Comment: Agree. I don't need to select them all. Just want to double click to select a word then all occurrences are highlighted to help quickly examining the document. How hard is that? After 2 years seems that this one is still not fully implemented.

Comment: @JimRaynor You can do that if "Highlight matches" is turned *off* in search. (Came here hoping to find a way to have both highlight at the same time. Looks like [this](https://github.com/SublimeText/WordHighlight) might do it.)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but just through the *Find* tool:

1. select the desired word (double-click on it; or click on it and press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>)
2. open the *Find* tool (with <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>) and ensure **Hightlight matches** is selected
3. navigate through the word instances (with <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> / <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>)

Or, as mentioned already, [WordHighlight plugin](https://github.com/SublimeText/WordHighlight) would fit your specific need.

The native way is not as straightforward & fast as with the plug-in, but it's pretty fast anyway; with the benefit of not having the multiple highlighting always happening regardless you want it or not.

And <kbd>double-click</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> is fast enough for me

Answer (score 0):

Install this package in sublime text

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/WordHighlight

Add this content in the `preferences -> package settings -> WordHighlight -> Settings User`

```
{
"color_scope_name": "comment",
"case_sensitive": false,
"draw_outlined": true,

"mark_occurrences_on_gutter" : true,
// valid types: dot, circle, bookmark and cross
"icon_type_on_gutter" : "dot",

"highlight_delay": 0,
"highlight_when_selection_is_empty": false,
"highlight_word_under_cursor_when_selection_is_empty": false,
"highlight_non_word_characters": true,

"file_size_limit": 4194304,
"when_file_size_limit_search_this_num_of_characters": 20000
}
```